# The meaning of "se faire"

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, prononciation, expressions-idiomatiques

What's the meaning of "se faire" or "me faire" ?

- Il me fait le philosophe.

I want to know the meaning of this sentence.

Comment: "Il se fait le philosophe" or "il me fait le philosophe"? There's a big difference.

Comment: So what's the difference..can you explain please?

Comment: *Il me faire le philosophe* is not correct French.

Comment: @jlliagre..I know that's why I'm asking cuz I saw it in a French song called On fleek..but I didn't get the meaning so please can you help me

Comment: And do you think that piece of information was not worth mentioning?

Comment:  thanks for answering

Comment: @Zuko I looked it up and the actual lyrics are "il me fait le philosophe". I edited your question.

Answer (score 6):

Eva's On Fleek song lyrics actually read:

> *Il m'fait le philosophe*

That's a colloquial way to say:

> He is playing/acting like a philosopher

Comment: So from where you know slang french expressions and words? Is there a website or something I can return to it?!

Comment: It's not really slang. *Faire le sth* is regular French (eg.: *Il fait le clown*) and in the dictionary: TLFi: [E.- 1. c)](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/faire)  *Imiter intentionnellement, chercher à passer pour. Synon. contrefaire, imiter, simuler.*. What is colloquial is adding *me*.

Answer (score 3):

The extra pronoun here is often known as the **ethic dative** (after the Latin *dativus ethicus* construction, although the pronoun is not expletive in Latin) or **dative of interest**. My edition of *Le Bon Usage* (14th ed.) prefers the former term (§672 b.3°e).

It doesn't have a grammatical function per se, but indicates that the person in question has some sort of serious/vested interest in the topic. Sometimes, it's addressed to the listener (*Je te retourne ça à l'envoyeur, moi!*), to emphasize instead that basically the action is very energetic. It's the same pronoun as found in orders of the form *Écoute/goûte/regarde-moi ça*, which you may be more familiar with.

In this particular instance, we would say in English that the speaker is being **philosophized at**, with the specific implication that the philosophical tangents are annoying or inconvenient.